# How to get seamless login to salesforce from my app which uses Azure AD as auth provider

Tags: azure, iframe, oauth, active-directory, saml

We have custom application which currently has a custom login page.
It integrates with Azure AD using the Oauth2 password grant type.
This works currently.

Once logged into the application, in one particular section of the website we need to embed a secure salesforce page via a iframe.

This salesforce page is setup to use oauth for the same Azure AD account - outside of the app, if we goto the salesforce page it will redirect to the azure login page (not our custom one) and we can then login and see the salesforce section (any subsequent accesses will not need the login prompt as the browser has recognised you have logged in previously)

However if we embed the secure salesforce page via a iframe, we get a

```
Refused to display http://xxx in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

We assume because this type of thing is not allowed with the Oauth2 spec, see: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23#section-10.13

Is it correct that the only way to have a secure salesforce page embedded on our site is to make our website a SAML provider so we can get around this specific oauth limitation?

If SAML is the way to go, how would this be implemented with this setup (struggling to find info on how to set it up like how we want) - can we keep our own login page (with some SAML specific changes) or would be forced to use the Azure login page?

Comment: You can also access Salesforce via the AAD Access Panel (myapps.microsoft.com).

Comment: unfortunately the client wants to access salesforce through our custom app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header has nothing to do with OAuth. It is a security feature that tells the browser to not load a page inside an iframe. This field is usually used to protect against [clickbait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickbait) attacks.

If the server responds with this header, there is usually no way to display the page in an iframe.